# How do I resolve: "Uncaught ReferenceError: buffer is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browserify, ipfs

I am attempting to submit a file with an HTML library using the IPFS Api. In order to do so I need to buffer the input before I add the file to IPFS.

My issue is that I have tried every option I've come across on the internet on how to resolve the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: buffer is not defined". I have reinstalled npm, Node, and used browserify with no success.

[image: Problem 1]
So what I did is I installed "npm install buffer" and went to the folder where index.js is located and used browserify to attempt to create a standalone buffer.js file.

```
browserify index.js -o buffer.js
```

I attempted to include the buffer.js file at the top of my HTML file and it changed the error to "require is not defined."

[image: Problem 2]

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript file upload</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="./buffer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ipfs-api@9.0.0/dist/index.js"
    integrity="sha384-5bXRcW9kyxxnSMbOoHzraqa7Z0PQWIao+cgeg327zit1hz5LZCEbIMx/LWKPReuB"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function upload() {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      const buf = require('buffer');
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        const ipfs = window.IpfsApi('localhost', 5001) // Connect to IPFS
        buf = buffer.Buffer(reader.result) // Convert data into buffer
        ipfs.files.add(buf, (err, result) => { // Upload buffer to IPFS
          if(err) {
            console.error(err)
            return
          }
          let url = `https://127.0.0.1:5001/ipfs/${result[0].hash}`
          console.log(`Url --> ${url}`)
          document.getElementById("url").innerHTML= url
          document.getElementById("url").href= url
          document.getElementById("output").src = url
        })
      }
      const photo = document.getElementById("photo");
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(photo.files[0]); // Read Provided File
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <form action="/">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload photo</legend>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo">
        <button type="button" onclick="upload()">Upload</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    </br>
    </br>
    <a id="url"></a>
    </br>
    </br>
    <img id="output">
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is what my project currently looks like:

[image: Project Directory]

**How can I get the above code to work by recognizing "buffer" with a local HTML file to upload files to IPFS in Windows 10?**

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ? If so can you share it ?

Comment: I apologize for not sharing my solution earlier. The solution was to use browserify (http://browserify.org/) on the file that requires the use of variable "buffer". In my case, this file was "buffer.js". I named the browserify output file "bundle.js" and included it and I no longer received the error "buffer is not defined."